# Como alterar a codificação dos caracteres no phpmailer

Tags: php, mailer

Não manjo nada de PHP. Nada. Zero. Niente. Ocorre que um formulário em uma página de um cliente em HTML simples é processado pelo PHPmailer.

Funciona que é uma beleza, mesmo que eu não faça a menor ideia de como.

Só que ele ENTREGA as mensagens no destino com os caracteres com outra codificação. Não tem jeito de alguém escrever no campo nome JOÃO e eu receber assim. Chega JoÃ£o.

Não sei onde é que muda isto, se tem como ou se me ferrei.

Alguém me dá um help?

Alguém?

Plis?

Answer (score 6):

**Helio**, use:

```
<?php

// Inclui o arquivo class.phpmailer.php localizado na pasta phpmailer
require_once("phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php");

// Inicia a classe PHPMailer
$mail = new PHPMailer();

// (...) codigos

// Define os dados técnicos da Mensagem
// =-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
//$mail->IsHTML(true); // Define que o e-mail será enviado como HTML
$mail->CharSet = 'iso-8859-1'; // Charset da mensagem (opcional)
```

Se `$mail->CharSet = 'iso-8859-1';` não funcionar, tente `$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';`!

Se mesmo assim não funcionar, veja se seu arquivo `.php` foi salvo com o charset correto. Veja no exemplo abaixo, o `Notepad++` alterando o charset do documento `.php`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Show. Uma pena eu não poder votar. Não tenho reputação alguma. Mas ó: valeu!

Comment: Heheh imagina! A comunidade irá ver o comentário. Abraço!

Answer (score 3):

Uma solução bem fácil é usar a função do PHP utf8_decode(). 
Supondo que você está enviando a mensagem via uma variável com o nome "mensagem" e de um campo chamado "mensagem", ficaria assim:

```
$mensagem = utf8_decode($_POST['mensagem']);
```

Você pode encontrar mais informações na documentaçãp:

http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.utf8-decode.php

Comment: Só assim resolveu pra mim, muito obrigado.